# Iframe abre em tela cheia em webview no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

Toda vez que coloco um iframe, ao invés de ele abrir dentro da página, o iframe abre em tela cheia. Segue códigos do projeto

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.duff.webviewoficial;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //aqui a mágica   REMOVE A BARRA DE TITULO
        getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Aparentemente habilitado

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return false;
         }
        });
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.duff.webviewoficial">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo_home_icon"
        android:label="FarmaLivPlayer"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

**Pagina com o problema home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view/matriz.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view/produtos.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view/paginas.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/banner.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/farmaLivPlayer.js"></script>

        <!-- evita abrir em iframe -->

        <script>if (self != top) { top.location.replace(window.location.href) }</script>

        <!-- evita abrir em iframe -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="view/master.css">



        <title></title>


    </head>
    <body onload="temporizarSlide()">


        <div id="tudo" >

            <div id="topo" class="transparente">
                    <div id="botaoMenu" class="botoesTopo">
                    <button class="js-menu-show header__menu-toggle material-icons"></button>

                    </div>
                <a href="javascript:home()"><div id="logo" class="botoesTopo"></div></a>
                <a href="javascript:cestinha()"><div id="botaoCestinha"></div></a>
                <div id="botaoLupa" ></div>
            </div>
        <div id="navegacao">
            <div id="banner" >



                    <div id="alvoBanner" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #ccc;">
                    <img src="view/img/sliders/1slide.png" width="100%" height="100%">

                    </div>
                        <a href="javascript:cliquePushDown()"><div id="pushDown" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0%;left: 50%; ;" onclick="cliquePushDown();"></a>
                        <a href="javascript:cliquePushDown()"><img src="view/img/sliders/pushDownBotao.png" width="100%" height="100%"></a>
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div id="sugestoes" >
                <div id="sugestoesFarmaLiv" class="block"></div>
                <div id="produtosContainer">
                    <iframe src="produtosApp/index.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="0"></iframe>
                    <div id="blockEsquerdo">
                    </div>
                    <div id="blockDireita">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="parceiros" class="transparente">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- fim da navegacao -->
            <div id="botoesFooter" class="transparente">
                <div id="botaoHome" class="botoesFooter" onclick="home()"></div>
                <div id="botaocategorias" class="botoesFooter" onclick="categorias()"></div>
                <div id="botaoDicasDeSaude" class="botoesFooter" onclick="dicasDeSaude()"></div>
                <div id="botaoPerfil" class="botoesFooter"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>

             <aside class="js-side-nav side-nav">
        <nav class="js-side-nav__container side-nav__container">
          <button class="js-menu-hide side-nav__hide material-icons">X</button>
          <header class="side-nav__header">

          </header>
          <ul class="side-nav__content">
            <li><a href="home.html">Início</li>
            <li><a href="busca.html">Busca</li>
            <!-- código Alerta de Saúde deletado -->
            <li><a href="categorias.html">Categorias</li><li><a href="dicasDeSaude.html">Dicas de saúde</li><li><a href="alertaDeSaude.html">Alerta de saúde</li><li><a href="#">Meus pedidos</li><li><a href="#">Minha conta</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </aside>
      <script src="js/side-nav.js"></script>


                    <div id="seletorImagem">

                    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você chegou a olhar aqui: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fullscreen

Comment: Uso tanto cordova quanto android studio. Não tenho problemas no Cordova para abrir iframe. Meu problema é no Android Studio. O iframe se recusa a abrir dentro de outra página. Ele carrega em tela cheia.
De verdade mesmo, eu só queria uma barra de status no app (bateria, sinal da operadora, horário), coisa que o Android Studio me dá fácil, e o phonegap/cordova não sei fazer. No android studio tenho barra de status, mas não tenho iframe. No cordova, tenho iframe, mas não tenho barra de status. Estou perdido kkk

Comment: Ali onde está seu getSupportActionBar().hide();, isso esta funcionando normalmente? Se você tira-lo vai mostrar a barra de título, porque o hide faz o trabalho de ocultar.

Comment: acabo de conferir! Está funcionando perfeitamente. Tanto que removi a linha e a barra de título voltou.

Comment: Minha dificuldade está em exibir o iframe dentro de uma webview no android studio. Isso não acontece! O iframe abre em tela cheia (editado)!

Comment: Basicamente você quer que o webview não abra em tela cheia, certo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55472/discussion-between-paulo-sergio-duff-and-ack-lay).

Comment: Eu acho que entendi a sua duvida, vc tem uma página no webView e está página tem um iframe, mas por algum motivo o iframe esta redirecionando a página `top` para o proprio endereço do iframe, seria isso? Ou será que o iframe está sendo invocado no navegador padrão?

Comment: **para o proprio endereço do iframe...**
 É isso mesmo! Ignorando a página que continha o iframe, e abrindo a página do iframe.